# How can I make sure my airflow DAG runs one day at a time?

Tags: task, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to set my DAG to run one day at a time. 
How can I achieve this?

I tried "depends on past=True", but it only makes sure each task is run subsequently. What I want is that, if I'm backfilling from day X, all tasks of day X are run before the DAG for day X+1 can start and so on.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `max_active_runs` to control the number of active dag runs.
Limiting it to one should satisfy your use case.

```
dag = airflow.DAG(
    'customer_staging',
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    template_searchpath=tmpl_search_path,
    default_args=args,
    max_active_runs=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this page](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#dag-runs). 
You can set up your schedule_interval with the following: `0 0 * * *`. 
If you have set up `catchup_by_default = True` with start_date several days ago, airflow will backfill all your previous tasks first then run the schedule based on `schedule_interval`.

Comment: This answer does not address how to run one day at a time. This answer will let the dag run multiple days at the same time when using catchup.